# Book: girl with a prototype computer in her head that allows her brain to be broken into multiple personalities

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find the name of a book I read about 15 years ago. The cover had a picture of a girl standing in front of a bunch of rockets.

The story was about a girl who finds out that a computer that was surgically implanted in her head is a prototype that allows for her brain to be broken into multiple personalities.

The company or government (I don't remember which) is trying to capture her again but she escapes and gets help from a hacker who helps her unlock her true potential.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*This Alien Shore* by C.S. Friedman? Published in 1998.
I can't find an edition with the cover you described, but the plot details are similar. [Here's a review](https://www.sfsite.com/09a/ali64.htm).

From a [Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36162.This_Alien_Shore):

> As Jamisia is trying to evade her unidentified pursuers, she also has to deal with the extra people who live in her head... If Earth finds out that she’s not normal, they will take her into custody.
>
> Fortunately, Jamisia meets a few people who can give her some help, though they’ve got their own issues to deal with. In particular, Phoenix the hacker is trying to trace the origin of Lucifer, a computer virus that’s killing his friends when they’re hooked into the Outernet.

Jamisia's brainware is a prototype.

Comment: thank you i must have confused the cover with a different book but this is it.

Answer (score -2):

William Hertling, [*Avogadro Corp*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/81189-singularity) series (2011).

First book's summary, from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13184491-avogadro-corp):

> David Ryan is the designer of ELOPe, an email language optimization program, that if successful, will make his career. But when the project is suddenly in danger of being canceled, David embeds a hidden directive in the software accidentally creating a runaway artificial intelligence.
>
> David and his team are initially thrilled when the project is allocated extra servers and programmers. But excitement turns to fear as the team realizes that they are being manipulated by an A.I. who is redirecting corporate funds, reassigning personnel and arming itself in pursuit of its own agenda.

Comment: Hi there. I edited in a blurb, but it'd be better if you could [edit] your post to explain how it matches, such as providing quotes or your own summary of the thing, as the book is more recent than what the question was looking for, and from a quick reading, doesn't seem to have a female lead?